# A poset derived from total order. What is it? Binomial poset?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a total order on a finite subset of natural numbers, say $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, with the $\leq$ relation. I produce a poset by making a finite number of copies of any chosen numbers, e.g $0\rightarrow 0',0''$, $2\rightarrow 2',2''$, $3\rightarrow 3'$. The copies are incomparable between themselves but they do inherit the $\leq$ relation from the original element. So for the example above we have:

[A graphical representation of the example poset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAYSs.png)

What sort of poset is this? Does it have a name? Was it studied anywhere? My colleague suggested it might be a binomial poset, but I think the definition (see below) is too general.

[Definition of binomial poset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l2CG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "graded" comes to mind. This is an exact example of a [graded set](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/graded+set) where the grading is by the set $\{0,\dots,n\}$. It is also an example of a [graded-poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_poset) meaning that it has a rank function. This poset has the additional property that

$$ \rho(x) < \rho(y) \implies x < y. $$

None of the examples on the Wikipedia page for graded-posets have this property, however (well, except for the total orders).

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a **weak order**, which is to say a partial order $W = (X, \leq)$ for which there exist no distinct $x,y,z \in X$ with $x \leq y$ and both $x$ and $y$ incomparable to $z$. In other words, a poset is a weak order if and only if it has no induced ${\mathbf 1}+{\mathbf 2}$.

For any weak order, the incomparability relation’s reflexive closure is an equivalence relation. In your case, each such equivalence class has the form $C_k=\{k, k^\prime, k^{\prime\prime}, \ldots, k^{(c)}\}$, containing exactly one of your original numbers $k$ and all its copies.
For your poset to include $x$, $y$, and $z$ as described above would mean that $x$ and $y$ were in distinct equivalence classes but each was in the same class as $z$.